Terminal in on a MacBook Pro (M2) is not working after setting a path. How can I fix it?
I tried to set Python path in .zshrc and save it. But after saving it, the terminal is not working anymore.
For all commands giving command not found and every time, I can see the path file in the terminal as I open it.
Please guide how to fix it.
/Users/bulu/.zshrc:export:6: not valid in this context: “/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/libexec/bin:/Users/bulu/.bin:/Users/bulu/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-21.0.2/Contents/Home/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/bulu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools”
bulu@Bulu-MacBook-Pro ~ % clear



From the error message, it looks like there's a problem with an export command on line 6 of /Users/bulu/.zshrc.

The core problem is shown in the error message:
/Users/bulu/.zshrc:export:6: not valid in this context: …

You should open up your ~/.zshrc in a text editor and look for what is causing the error on line 6 or just delete whatever is on line 6.
Or you should just be able to get your user’s .zshrc regenerated by running this command and restarting your machine:
rm -f ~/.zshrc

Better yet, if you want to play it safe, you can just move the file by running this command and then restart your machine:
mv ~/.zshrc ~/.zshrc.damaged


Yes, I am able to find out the .zshrc files under Users and after removing that line, it is working now. Thank you so much for the solution everyone.
